# What is wrong with my function to get all subsets of a list?

Tags: python

```
def getAllSubsets(lst):
    """
        lst: A list
    Returns the powerset of lst, i.e. a list of all the possible subsets of lst
    """

    if not lst:
        return []
    withFirst = [[lst[0]] + rest for rest in getAllSubsets(lst[1:])]
    withoutFirst = getAllSubsets(lst[1:])
    return withFirst + withoutFirst
```

I don't fully understand how it is managing to getAllSubsets of given list. This function was provided to me, not written by me. An explanation of how it works would be appreciated.

Comment: So you can think of getting all subsets of some set A as choosing to include the element or not include an element from A. Thus, if there are 5 elements in A, the set of all subsets of A has 2^5 elements, since at each element there is a choice to include or not include that element (two choices, five elements). I suspect the above method is a recursive implementation of this idea.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. There doesn't seem to be a valid question here. You ask "what is wrong with my function", but you tell us that it is not actually your code. If the question is actually "how does this code work?", then you should ask it like that; but such questions are generally off topic here. The problem is that we cannot just "explain" something to you in a vacuum because *we have no way to know why you don't already understand it*. If the question is "why doesn't this work", then you need to explain what goes wrong when you use it.

Comment: "I don't fully understand how it is managing to getAllSubsets of given list." I can't understand this. You ask what is wrong with the code (and I tested it, and indeed it doesn't work). So how can you also ask how it is doing the task, if it *doesn't correctly do the task*?

Comment: Anyway, the problem is a simple typo: `return []` should be `return [[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title and question body are contradictory, as the former makes it sound like there's a problem with the program and you're trying to figure out what it is. The problem with the program is that the line `return []` is returning an empty list, when instead it should be returning a list containing an empty list. As for the body of the question, that is asking for an explanation for how the program is supposed to work:

The basic idea of the program that given an original set A and subset B, it is the case that for every element of A, it either is or isn't in B. That is, B can be constructed by going through each element of A, and for that element, making a decision as to whether to include it or not. This then suggests a recursive algorithm for creating subsets: given a set A, consider the "tail" of A. By that I mean, all the elements of A other than the "first" one (sets don't really have a first element, but the input to this function is actually a list, rather than a set, so there is a first element). Find all the subsets for the tail of A, then, for each subset that you find that way, create two subsets: one that includes the first element of A, and another that doesn't.

So how the algorithm works is that it sets the first element of the input aside, then calls the function on the remaining elements, get all the resulting subsets, and for each of them creates two subsets, one with and one without the element that was set aside. Of course, if you keep removing the first element, you'll eventually get an empty list. So the algorithm first checks whether the list is empty, and if so, returns that the only subset is the null set.

There are some ways the function can be improved. The biggest thing is that it calls `getAllSubsets(lst[1:]` twice. Unless you have a really smart compiler/interpreter that can recognize that and only actually run it once, you're doing much more work than you need to. I think it's even more than twice as much work, because you're doubling the amount of work *at each level of recursion*. So if there are five levels of recursion, you'll be running the lowest level 32 times as much. You could also hardcode the first level of recursion by just taking the null set and the element, although that's somewhat abandoning the simplicity of a pure recursion algoritm.

```
def getAllSubsets(lst):
    """
        lst: A list
    Returns the powerset of lst, i.e. a list of all the possible subsets of lst
    """

    if not lst:
        return [[]]
    # you can remove the above two lines if you're sure 
    # that the original call isn't on an empty list
    tail = lst[1:]
    if not tail:
        return [[],[lst[0]]
    tail_subsets = getAllSubsets(tail)
    withFirst = [[lst[0]] + rest for rest in tail_subsets]
    return tail_subsets + withFirst
```

Comment: "So if there are five levels of recursion, you'll be running the lowest level 32 times." Doesn't matter very much; the code will still have to do O(2^N) work because *the correct output has O(2^N) elements*. You have almost fixed the bug by adding an extra base case, such that the original buggy base case is skipped. However, by definition the powerset of an empty set *should* contain one element (which is the empty set). The base case should simply be `if not lst: return [[]]`, and this is sufficient on its own.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Good point that it should be a list containing an empty list, rather just an empty list. But I'm not convinced that the duplication doesn't matter. I think it adds a factor of 2^n on top of the base 2^n.

Comment: Constant factors aren't counted in big-O notation.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 2^n isn't a constant factor.

Comment: if you do 2^n + 2^n, you get 2(2^n), and the 2 is a constant factor.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "Adding a factor" meaning multiplying. It's "adding" in the sense of "additional", not in the sense of "sum".

Answer (score 0):

Karl has already pointed out the error in the original code, and I think explanations have been offered for how the recursion works, but we can also make the code shorter in the following way:

```
def powersetlist(s):
    r = [[]]
    for e in s:
        r+=[x+[e] for x in r]
    
    return r
```

Here, we update what is in r at every element e in our list s, and then add the new subsets with e to our existing r. I think we avoid recursion in this case.

Output for [1,2,3,4]:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], 
[1, 2, 3], [4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], 
[3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: yes; this basically reuses the recursive call result, and then straightforwardly converts simple tail recursion to iteration. Well spotted.